# Martingale exercise

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, martingales

I'm struggling with an exercise from a martingales theory book:

> Let $M$ be an $F$-martingale and $Z$ an adapted (bounded) continuous process. Prove that:
>   $$
> \mathbb{}E\left(M_t\int_s^tZ_u \, du \mid \mathcal{F}_s \right)=\mathbb{}E\left(\int_s^t M_u Z_u \, du \mid \mathcal{F}_s\right)
> $$

It was given just after the Doob-Meyer decomposition theorem.

I started from the right term interverting integral and expectation signs:
$$
\mathbb{}E\left(\int_s^t M_u Z_u \, du \mid \mathcal{F}_s\right)=\mathbb{}\int_s^tE\left( M_u Z_u \mid \mathcal{F}_s\right) \, du
$$
but I didn't see where it could lead.

Any hint (not a solution) would be appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $M$ is a martingale, we have

$$M_u Z_u = \mathbb{E}(M_t \mid \mathcal{F}_u) Z_u = \mathbb{E}(M_t Z_u \mid \mathcal{F}_u)$$

for any $u \leq t$. Now integrate both sides over $u \in [s,t]$ and take the conditional expectation with respect to $\mathcal{F}_s$